# getDegree()/isOutgoing() funcitons don't work in graphAware/neo4j-to-elasticsearch mapping.json

Tags: json, neo4j, graphaware

Neo4j Version: 3.2.2

Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04

I use `getDegree()` function in mapping.json file, but the return would always be `null`; I'm using the dataset neo4j tutorial Movie/Actor dataset.

[**Output from elasticsearch request**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCAMm.png)

**mapping.json**

```
{
  "defaults": {
    "key_property": "uuid",
    "nodes_index": "default-index-node",
    "relationships_index": "default-index-relationship",
    "include_remaining_properties": true
  },
  "node_mappings": [
    {
      "condition": "hasLabel('Person')",
      "type": "getLabels()",
      "properties": {
        "getDegree": "getDegree()",
        "getDegree(type)": "getDegree('ACTED_IN')",
        "getDegree(direction)": "getGegree('OUTGOING')",
        "getDegree('type', 'direction')": "getDegree('ACTED_IN', 'OUTGOING')",
        "getDegree-degree": "degree"
      }
    }
  ],
  "relationship_mappings": [
    {
      "condition": "allRelationships()",
      "type": "type",
    }
  ]
}
```

Also if I use `isOutgoing(), isIncoming(), otherNode` function in relationship_mappings properties part, elasticsearch would never load the relationship data from neo4j. I think I probably have some misunderstanding of this sentence `only when one of the participating nodes "looking" at the relationship is provided` on this page https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-framework/tree/master/common#inclusion-policies

**mapping.json**

```
{
  "defaults": {
    "key_property": "uuid",
    "nodes_index": "default-index-node",
    "relationships_index": "default-index-relationship",
    "include_remaining_properties": true
  },
  "node_mappings": [
    {
      "condition": "allNodes()",
      "type": "getLabels()"
    }
  ],
  "relationship_mappings": [
    {
      "condition": "allRelationships()",
      "type": "type",
      "properties": {
        "isOutgoing": "isOutgoing()",
        "isIncomming": "isIncomming()",
        "otherNode": "otherNode"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

BTW, is there any page that list all of the functions that we can use in mapping.json? I know two of them

1. `github.com/graphaware/neo4j-framework/tree/master/common#inclusion-policies`
2. `github.com/graphaware/neo4j-to-elasticsearch/blob/master/docs/json-mapper.md`
   **but** it seems there are more, since I can use `getType()`, which hasn't been listed in any of the above pages.

Please let me know if I can provide any further help to solve the problem

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `getDegree()` function is not available to use, in contrary to `getType()`. I will explain why :

When the mapper (the part responsible to create a node or relationship representation as ES document ) is doing its job, it receive a `DetachedGraphObject` being a detached node or relationship.

The meaning of `detached` is that it is happening outside of a transaction and thus query operations are not available against the database anymore. The `getType()` is available because it is part of the relationship metadata and it is cheap, however if we would want to do the same for `getDegree()` this can be seriously more costly during the `DetachedObject` creation (which happen in a tx) depending on the number of different types etc.

This is however something we are working on, by externalising the mapper in a standalone java application coupled with a broker like kafa, rabbit,.. between neo and this app. We would not, however offer the possibilty to requery the graph in the current version of the module as it can have serious performance impacts if the user is not very careful.

As last, the only suggestion I can give you is to keep a property on your node with the updates of degrees you need to replicate to ES.

**UPDATE**

Regarding this part of the documentation :

For Relationships only when one of the participating nodes "looking" at the relationship is provided:

This is used only when not using the json definition, so you can use one or the other. the json definition has been added later as addition and both cannot be used together.

For answering this part, it means that the nodes of the incoming or outgoing side, depending on the definition, should be included in the inclusion policy for nodes, like `hasLabel('Employee') || hasProperty('form') || getProperty('age', 0) > 20` . If you have an `allNodes` policy then it is fine.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, Christophe! one more question, what does `only when one of the participating nodes "looking" at the relationship is provided` mean in https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-framework/tree/master/common#inclusion-policies mean? I want to use isIncoming()/isOutgoing() function for relationship and how can I provide `the nodes that "looking" at the relationship`

Comment: Thanks! now I understand it

Comment: Is creating a property on your node with updates of degrees you need in ES still the best practice approach today?

Comment: It is still yes, and easily doable with triggers such as GraphAware neo4j-triggers or APOC triggers

Comment: Indeed I tried doing so with the APOC trigger however this did not trigger a Bulk operation in the GraphAware-ElasticSearch plugin, could you look at this related questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59897342/apoc-trigger-transaction-not-resulting-in-a-graphaware-elasticsearch-bulk-operat